# jQuery; apply styling on classes created from the values of dynamically created variables

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover

After generating some variables dynamically, i want to use their values for finding classes and apply some style on each one of them. This is what I've tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var input = []
    var message = []        
    for(var n=1; n<=3; n++) {
        input[n] = 'text' + n; //this will create three variables with the values text1, text2 and text3
        message[n] = 'tip' + n; //this will create three variables with the values tip1, tip2 and tip3
        $('.' + input[n]).mouseover(function() {
            $('.' + message[n]).css("display", "block"); 
        });
        $('.' + input[n]).mouseout(function() {
            $('.' + message[n]).css("display", "none"); 
        });
    }
});
```

So the logic I want is:

- When hovering on the class text1, tip1 should display (otherwise tip1 will be hidden)
- When hovering on the class text2, tip2 should display (otherwise tip2 will be hidden)
- When hovering on the class text3, tip3 should display (otherwise tip3 will be hidden)

The planned logic only works if I provided a -harcoded- value on `n`, but the value of `n` could change in the coming future to a higher one (e.g. 4, 5 or more), so I wondered if there is a generic way to apply that logic.

Could someone help me out a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using selectors with document mouseover/mouseout events. Just use "input" and "message" as your classes and use the data attribute to connect inputs to messages.

PHP:

```
<?php 
    for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
    {
        echo '<span class="input" data-anchor="'.$i.'">This is input '.$i.'</span>';
        echo '<span class="message" data-anchor="'.$i.'" style="display:none">This is message '.$i.'</span><br>';
    }
?>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.input', function(){
    var anchor = $(this).data('anchor');
    $('.message[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').show();
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.input', function(){
    var anchor = $(this).data('anchor');
    $('.message[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').hide();
});
```